# How to specify python paths in pyproject.toml for poetry?

Tags: python, python-poetry

I want to build a poetry python environment by setting the pyproject.toml file so when I activate it and running in python interpreter `import sys; print(sys.path)` will show the paths added in pyproject.toml

How to proceed ?

Comment: That is a bit of a weird thing to want to do. That is not what Poetry is for. Maybe we need to reconsider why you want to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tool.poetry.packages` and their `from` attribute so that those paths are added to the *.pth file managed by poetry when installing.

This example pyproject.toml

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "asdf"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ["Your Name <you@example.com>"]
readme = "README.md"

packages = [
    { include = "foo", from = "lib" },
    { include = "bar", from = "src"},
]


[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.11"


[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

with the following folder tree

```
|-- pyproject.toml
|-- README.md
|-- src
|   \-- bar
|       \-- __init__.py
\-- lib
    \-- foo
        \-- __init__.py
```

when installed with `poetry install` will create a myproject.pth file in the virtual environment such that

```
python -c 'import os,sys; print(os.linesep.join(sys.path))'
```

will contain

```
/path/to/my/projects/asdf/src
/path/to/my/projects/asdf/lib
```

Make sure to read the documentation to understand all caveats, e.g.

> Using `packages` disables the package auto-detection feature meaning you have to **explicitly** specify the “default” package.

https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/#packages